# Jekyll tag_gen plugin not working

Tags: plugins, tags, jekyll

I'm trying to install `tag_gen.rb` plugin on my Jekyll. I found this solution [here](http://charliepark.org/tags-in-jekyll/). I copied it into the folder:

```
 ~/_plugins/tag_gen.rb
```

Created layout:

```
 ~/_layouts/tag_index.html
```

Specified some tags at my post:

```
---
tags: [tag1, tag2, tag3]
---
```

I set `safe: false` at `_config.yml`. I run Jekyll server by such commands:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
jekyll --server
```

Jekyll version is:

```
jekyll -v
Jekyll 0.12.0
```

After I installed it, nothing happens. I expect new pages at `tags` folder, but it's empty. Also I don't see any errors at console while Jekyll execution.

What I'm doing wrong? How to find an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a problem. All my tags have url `~/tags/tag_name`, but jekyll generate them at folder `~/_site/tag`. So, I copied it's content form `~/_site/tag` to `~/tags/` and everything working fine.