# jekyll tag plugin works offline but not on github pages

Tags: ruby, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-extensions

There might seem to be other dupes like this, but [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375331/jekyll-tag-gen-plugin-not-working) is the closest with a hacky solution.

I got a theme that uses the tag plugin from here : http://charliepark.org/tags-in-jekyll/ Here is [my site repo on github](https://github.com/gideondsouza/gideondsouza/tree/gh-pages). It's hosted here : http://www.gideondsouza.com

Tags **don't work online** but work offline. On my local machine I see a `_/site/tag/..` with folders for each tag. But this tag folder isn't generated on github? In fact I don't even see a `_site` folder, so maybe my understanding is off. Perhaps I need to install the github-pages gem?

I could probably fix it like in the SO post mentioned earlier, but this is hacky, I will always have to remember to copy the generated tags folder into the root.

Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Github pages only support selected plugins ([see documentation here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-jekyll-plugins-to-a-github-pages-site/)).

If you want to use your plugin, you have to generate locally and to push the `_site` content online.

Comment: Direct link to the plugins supported by Github Pages: https://pages.github.com/versions/

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. The `_site` folder is generated already but the `.gitignore` has it so I'm guessing I'll remove it from there and just build and push it online.